# clearInterval before setTimeout wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I have a problem with clearing an interval. I have 3 functions `start1`, `start2`, `start3`. Here you can see only the first. The function `count1` and variable `myVar1` have the same princip they are the same numbered. Now the problem is that `clearInterval` only works after the first function (See console log). After the second `start2()` anything happens what I cant explain by myself. I made a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ncc3d8vc/17/).

```
start1();

function start1() {
    var valuem = 0, dir = 1;
    $('#number').text(valuem);

    function count1() {
        valuem += dir;
        $('#number').text(valuem);
        if (valuem < 1) dir = 1;
        console.log("start1");
    }

    $("body").on({
        'touchstart mousedown': function(e) {
            if ($('#number').text() == 5) {
                window.clearInterval(myVar1);
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                    start2();
                }, 1000);
            }
        },
        'touchend mouseup': function(e) {}
    });

    var myVar1 = window.setInterval(function() {
        count1();
    }, 1000);
}
```

console log:

```
5 start1

6 start2

start3

start2

start3

start2
```

Comment: I don't get that output from your demo. It just keeps doing 'start1'.

Comment: Why declare an anonimous function wrapping count1 ?  Use count1 directly in the setInterval ....

Comment: what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @GolezTrol please kepp going after you clicked first at 5, then starts ´start2()´

Comment: It does, but when I do, I get only start2, no start1 anymore. And I can't get to start3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code goes wrong after second function call is You did not unset `mousedown touchstart` event when you call next one.
So at the time you run the second function, You have 2 event listener on `body` and both of them works. this causes the issue.

So unset the event listener when you call next one.

```
$("body").on({
    'touchstart mousedown': function(e) {
        if (parseInt($('#number').text()) >= 5) {
            $(e.target).off('touchstart mousedown');
            window.clearInterval(myVar1);
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                start2();
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

The code above uses `>=5` instead of your original code `$('#number').text() == 5` to make it easily checkable how it works.