# stopping interval wont work sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a problem with stopping the execution of a function. I have 10 functions named start1, start2, start3, ... Then I have all numbered in the functions like that how you can see in the snippet. All start functions have only different numerations the other is always the same. Now the problem is that sometimes (not every time) after the `start3` function the Interval wont be cleared. Sometimes this happens too after the 7. function. What can cause this behaviour?

```
var valuem = 0, dir = 1;
    start1();
    function start1() {

    $('#number').text(valuem);

    function count1() {
        valuem += dir;
        $('#number').text(valuem);
        if (valuem < 1)  { dir = 1; }       
        console.log("start1");
    }       

     $("body").on({
        'touchstart mousedown': function (e) {

        if ($('#number').text() > 5) {
        window.clearInterval(myVar1);
        $(e.target).off('touchstart mousedown');

    window.setTimeout(function(){ start2(); 
    }, 1000);

        }
        else {
        $(e.target).off('touchstart mousedown');
        clearInterval(myVar1);
        console.log("fail");
        }    
        }
    });    
    var myVar1 = window.setInterval(count1, 1000);
    }


    function start2() {
  valuem = 0, dir = 1;
    $('#number').text(valuem);

    function count2() {
        valuem += dir;
        $('#number').text(valuem);
        if (valuem < 1)  { dir = 1; }       
        console.log("start1");
    }       

     $("body").on({
        'touchstart mousedown': function (e) {

        if ($('#number').text() > 5) {
        window.clearInterval(myVar2);
        $(e.target).off('touchstart mousedown');

    window.setTimeout(function(){ start3(); 

    }, 1000);

        }
        else {
        $(e.target).off('touchstart mousedown');
        clearInterval(myVar2);
        console.log("fail");
        }    
        }
    });    
    var myVar2 = window.setInterval(count2, 1000);
    }
```

**console:**

5 start3

start4

start3

start4

start3

Comment: Is there a specific difference between this and your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837166/clearinterval-before-settimeout-wont-work)? It also seems that this is a bit of an XY problem. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but I am sure that 10 near identical functions isn't the way to do it.

Comment: Maybe it is because you created the variables Myvars after you try to call it with clearInterval?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Now the problem occurs not every time and I fixed an mistake. But yes they are pretty the same. How should I do it right?

Comment: @Koen It doesnt make any difference :(

Comment: @klamertd I'm not sure - you've not described what you're trying to achieve, only what's happening.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan When the variable ´valuem´ is over 5 when the user clicks the next start function should be executed and the previous stopped. Now overlap them sometimes and I cant explain myself why...

Comment: Why do you need different functions to do that? Why not just call the same function again?

Comment: Yes youre right I made it in one function its ways simpler. Thank you :D